# What is the price of Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition, with the 5 user cals

Tags: 2010

What is the price (in US Dollars) of SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition, with the 5 user cals?

I can't seem to find this pricing anywhere. Whenever I ask one of the "local" resellers, the response is always that "we need to come in and have a discussion"; it's like a well kept secret.

Comment: Of course it's a well-kept secret, they throw in lots of consultancy too ;)

Comment: QUESTION:
And the AD CALs, doesn't have nothing to do about this? or is something completely different?

Comment: @fallout, Active Directory CALs? I haven't heard of it. Just Operating System CALS. This is about pricing for SharePoint including the operating system

Comment: Licensing prices and rules regularly change, and what applies to one country is different to another. Hence the closure of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a complicated question, because it can be licensed a variety of ways.

Just SharePoint Enterprise (not SQL, OS, etc) - these are high end retail, you'll get if for less under Open Value or another volume program.

Server license $5000
Standard CAL $92
Enterprise CAL $75

1 Server 5 Cal - $5835

These sites have more details.
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Licensing-Details.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/#tab=1

I would recommend you look at a hosted deployment, it will probably be more cost effective for you with that few of users.

Comment: Yea cuz after the os cal + sql server cal + sharepoint cal, you're looking at alot of mula for a small company.

How come standard is more expensive than enterprise?

Comment: They are cumulative licenses.  Standard CAL = Standard Server, Standard + Enterprise CAL = Enterprise Server.

Comment: Oh, so you need a standard cal for the enterprise cal. So the enterprise cal is actually: $167

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

While this is not exact, but will give you an idea. If you can unravel the exact pricing concept (cal, internet, intranet etc. licenses), pls do us a favor by sharing that :-)

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010-price-calculator/default.aspx

Comment: If I do, then of course.