# SharePoint 2010 Server CALs

Tags: 2010, licensing

I've a SharePoint 2010 Server Enterprise with 10 Enterprise CALs for a lot more users(all with AD CALs) but until now, all access's were succeed. So far, so good.

But after I take a deeper look into [this](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010-price-calculator/default.aspx) calculator and some other info I'm not so sure if the above features are enough.

Is the SP Standard CALs the same as the Server CALs ?

Can anyone enlighten me in this question?

SPRegards!

Comment: You can refer to a series of posts (http://stovereffect.com/2010/06/29/sharepoint-2010-licensing-part-i-the-basics/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bas is correct, you need to work with a specialist to ensure participate with the correct program and are licensed correctly.

I covered a similar question here:

[What is the price of Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition, with the 5 user cals](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14540/what-is-the-price-of-sharepoint-2010-enterprise-edition-with-the-5-user-cals/14544#14544)

Answer (score 1):

The best information you can get about licenses is to contact with your Microsoft representative. Licensing with microsoft products can be very complex and I think that they are very willing to help you ;)